# getting error while starting service from ADB :Error: Not found; no service started

Tags: android, service, adb

I am trying to start a service from ADB via the following command -

```
adb shell am startservice -n com.ixigo/.mypnrlib.service.SMSParsingService -a com.ixigo.mypnrlib.ACTION_PARSE_EXISTING_MESSAGES
```

I get the following response

Starting service: Intent { act=com.ixigo.mypnrlib.ACTION_PARSE_EXISTING_MESSAGES cmp=com.ixigo/.mypnrlib.service.SMSParsingService }
Error: Requires permission not exported from uid 10693

Now when i specify the user via --user argument and the application is up and running via the same userID:

```
adb shell am startservice --user 10693 -n com.ixigo/.mypnrlib.service.SMSParsingService -a com.ixigo.mypnrlib.ACTION_PARSE_EXISTING_MESSAGES
```

I get the following message:

Starting service: Intent { act=com.ixigo.mypnrlib.ACTION_PARSE_EXISTING_MESSAGES cmp=com.ixigo/.mypnrlib.service.SMSParsingService }
Error: Not found; no service started.

I do not want to expose the service Is there any other way we can call it from ADB ?

Comment: Are you using a root shell? If not refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047962/adb-broadcast-with-user-id

Comment: @SamT01 thanks, that explains well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @SamT01 's comment. There is no way we can call a non exported component from non-root ADB.